# which transaction manager should I use (JTA vs JPA)?

Tags: spring, jpa, jta

I have spring 4 application. At the moment I use JpatransactionManager.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Could you tell me how to choose transaction managers?

For instance, when should I use jta transaction manager and when jpa, and what benefit and disadvantages does they have?

And Is I know I have 2 way to work in Spring. First is JPA way and the second Hibernate way.  first one includes java standard annotations and standard api and the second is hibenrate implementation. If i need to use JTA, I must use hibernate and not JPA, does not it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to delegate managed transactions to your Application Server and handle complex transactions across multiple resources you need to use the JtaTransactionManager, but I believe it is not needed in most cases. 
Read this for more information http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

> **Do you need an application server for transaction management?**
>
> The Spring Framework’s transaction management support changes
>   traditional rules as to when an enterprise Java application requires
>   an application server.
>
> In particular, you do not need an application server simply for
>   declarative transactions through EJBs. In fact, even if your
>   application server has powerful JTA capabilities, you may decide that
>   the Spring Framework’s declarative transactions offer more power and a
>   more productive programming model than EJB CMT.
>
> Typically you need an application server’s JTA capability only if your
>   application needs to handle transactions across multiple resources,
>   which is not a requirement for many applications. Many high-end
>   applications use a single, highly scalable database (such as Oracle
>   RAC) instead. Standalone transaction managers such as Atomikos
>   Transactions and JOTM are other options. Of course, you may need other
>   application server capabilities such as Java Message Service (JMS) and
>   Java EE Connector Architecture (JCA).
>
> The Spring Framework gives you the choice of when to scale your
>   application to a fully loaded application server. Gone are the days
>   when the only alternative to using EJB CMT or JTA was to write code
>   with local transactions such as those on JDBC connections, and face a
>   hefty rework if you need that code to run within global,
>   container-managed transactions. With the Spring Framework, only some
>   of the bean definitions in your configuration file, rather than your
>   code, need to change.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks !!